# How to modify or remove the No SIM Card message on lock screen?

Tags: cyanogenmod, lock-screens, 5.1-lollipop, oneplus-two

Just in case: I'm using a OnePlus Two US Model (ONE A2005 / tocino) running Android 5.1.1 with MoKee (MK51.1-tocino-160403-RELEASE). I have root and xposed running as well. Using Nova Launcher, but lock screen is built in with the ROM (as in unchanged).

I'm been looking for a way to remove the "No SIM Card - Emergency calls only" from my lock screen. It would be better if I can modify the line with a custom message; replacing it, basically.

I tried looking for this online, but the only resources I found is to remove the No SIM Card icon and notification on the home screen.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: If your device is rooted, you could try Xposed with the [HideMissingSIM](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.defim.apk.hidemissingsim) module. Promises to remove it from the status bar. Not sure if it also removes it from the lockscreen itself. [Hide No SIM icon](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.wedy.screenmute) promises the same – again no mention of the lock screen.

Comment: @Izzy Thank you, but I already installed this module. arana below works.

Comment: I have the same annoying issue on my OPX (E1003). Though it happens rarely, the only way to get rid of it is to *reboot the phone*. Still not sure what causes it.

Comment: Shiyaz If you still have this issue you can try some of what I answered below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are rooted and comfortable with custom ROMs and Xposed etc, you can use [Clean Lockscreen](http://repo.xposed.info/module/gd.sec.cleanlockscreen).

If you don't want to use an Xposed module, add the following line to your build.prop file: (**After you made a backup!**)

```
ro.config.donot_nosim=true
```

Now reboot your device. If you still see this message change this line:

```
ro.config.tima=1
```

To this:

```
#ro.config.tima=1
```

Then reboot your phone, and if that didn't work, change the previous line to this:

```
ro.config.tima=0
```

Comment: Thank you! Clean Lockscreen is working perfectly to remove the No SIM Card notification.